# Github GH Pages changes font for h1

Tags: html, css, github, fonts

I am using a font through edge fonts and am hosting the static html page through github pages. However, when I look at the link, the h1 font has changed. When I look at it in my local host, it has the correct font. Does anyone know how to correct this?

In my index.html

```
<script src='http://use.edgefonts.net/londrina-shadow.js'></script>
<style>
h1 {
font-family: londrina-shadow, sans-serif;
font-size: 150px;
}
</style>
<h1>TITLE</h1>
```

Comment: Any link to your page or example of code?

Comment: I added some sample code

Answer (score 0):

Set the H1 code in the .css page, not the HTML.

```
    h1 {
     font-family: londrina-shadow, sans-serif;
     font-size: 150px;
    }
```

Put that in the .css page and see what happens. Also eliminate the h1 font-family preset from the Github theme.

Comment: Thanks will try that. Also how do you remove the font-family preset from the GitHub theme?

Comment: Find the font-family currently present in one of the .css pages and delete it there.